# Read json file written by Chrome Extension stdout

Tags: windows, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, stdout

the chrome extension outputs json file to stdout. I want to read this json file from my python application. my application is using selenium and load this extension to the chrome browser. my environment is windows 7.

Comment: Extensions can't write to stdout directly. Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) I can only guess you mean **nativeMessaging** API in which case the answer and a Python demo extension is in the  documentation.

Comment: thanks,I posted the code of the extension: if(program.webhook){
        async function sendLogs(){
            if(!logs.length) return; //nothing to send
            console.log('posting logs to '+program.webhook)
            await postJson(program.webhook, logs)
            logs = []
        }
        await sendLogs()
        process.on('exit', sendLogs) //XXX: will this actually work?
        process.on('SIGQUIT', sendLogs)
        process.on('SIGINT', sendLogs)
        process.on('SIGTERM', sendLogs)
        setInterval(sendLogs, 30*1000) //periodically send events
    }